# Movie title: two planets heading towards the Earth

Tags: story-identification, movie

I saw the movie as a kid, so it was probably from the '80s. It's about two planets heading towards the Earth. The first one passes close by, causing floods, earthquakes, etc. The second one (spoiler alert) hits the Earth.

That's all I remember. Anybody knows the movie?

Comment: When Worlds Collide? Do some earth people migrate to one of the two planets in a spaceship?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/When_Worlds_Collide_(1951_film) That one??

Comment: More recently Melancholia. The planet passed by causing only mild disruption, then doubles back and kills the Earth

Comment: @user14111 Yes! I completely forgot about that

Answer (score 15, accepted):

That sounds very much like the plot of the 1951 film *When Worlds Collide*.

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/When_Worlds_Collide_(1951_film)):

"The plot concerns the coming destruction of the Earth by a rogue star called Bellus and the desperate efforts to build a space ark to transport a group of men and women to Bellus' single planet, Zyra."

The planet Zyra passes close to Earth, causing devastating floods and earthquakes.  Then the star Bellus collides with Earth, annihilating it.

The only way to save something of humanity is to launch a space ark and resettle on the planet Zyra.

Comment: [Originally a novel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/When_Worlds_Collide).

Comment: That's the one, thanks! Also @Spencer thanks for that, I see now there's also a sequel novel